# Find words that are evenly short and print them all

Tags: java, arrays, split

I need to write a program that will find out shortest words in the given string str. My inputs are;

> olive, fish, pursuit, warning, old, python, java, coffee, cat, ray
>
> volt, olive, fish, hot pursuit, warning, python, java, coffee, part

When i input first iteration which is "olive, fish, pursuit, warning, old, python, java, coffee, cat, ray" it gives me [cat, old, ray]

but when I input the second iteration which is "volt, olive, fish, hot pursuit, warning, python, java, coffee, part" it gives me "coffee and python" whereas needs to output [fish, java, part, volt] ?????

Do you think it's related to Arrays.sort ???

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = scan.nextLine();
        String[] words = str.split(", ");
        Arrays.sort(words);
        String shortest = words[0];
        String count = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < words.length ; i++) {
            if(shortest.length() <= words[i].length() && words[i].length() == shortest.length()){
                shortest = words[i];
                count += shortest+", ";
            }
        }
        if(count.length() > 0){
            count = count.replaceAll(", $", "");
            System.out.print("["+count+"]");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoveflow. What is your question exacly ?

Comment: Hi there, I need to find all shortest words in an array with the given inputs. Thanks!

Comment: And can you explain what is not working in your current code ?

Comment: As Nicolas said, what is the problem you're facing specifically? What is your current output, and what is the expected output?

Comment: When i input first iteration which is "olive, fish, pursuit, warning, old, python, java, coffee, cat, ray" it gives me [cat, old, ray] but when I input the second iteration which is "volt, olive, fish, hot pursuit, warning, python, java, coffee, part" it gives me coffee and python whereas needs to output [fish, java, part, volt]

Comment: it looks like you need an else so that if you don't already have the shortest word, you reset shortest

Comment: still the same!

Comment: see my answer below for what I meant about the else. Also, no your Arrays.sort is not messing it up, just alphabetizing before finding the shortest one(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sorting the words, but I assume you wanted to sort them by length, not alphabetically, so that `words[0]` is indeed the `shortest`. For this, you have to provide a specific `Comparator`.

```
Arrays.sort(words, Comparator.comparing(String::length));
```

If you want to get the shortest words in alphabetical order, sort *first* by length and *then* by natural (alphabetic) order.

```
Arrays.sort(words, Comparator.comparing(String::length)
                             .thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

Now the rest of your code will work. However, your main loop is a bit redundant. You do not have to check whether the length is `<=` and `==`, just `==` is enough, and you do not have to update `shortest` each time.

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length ; i++) {
    if (words[i].length() == shortest.length()){
        count += words[i] + ", ";
    }
}
```

Or using just `Arrays.sort(words);`, you can look at two cases: If the word is smaller, remember the new `smallest` and reset `count`, and if it's equally small add to `count`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length ; i++) {
    if (words[i].length() < shortest.length()){
        shortest = words[i];
        count = "";
    }
    if (words[i].length() == shortest.length()){
        count += words[i] + ", ";
    }
}
```

Alternatively, using Java 8 Stream API to first get the min length, then all words with that length.

```
int len = Stream.of(words).mapToInt(String::length).min().getAsInt();
String count = Stream.of(words).filter(w -> w.length() == len)
        .sorted().collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! It all worked out! Last question tho; How can i print them all in an alphabetical order?

Comment: @mistersholmes Using `stream`, just add `sorted()` somewhere in between. Using the first approach, it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: Dude! You're the best! THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 1):

To work with your original idea, you would want:

```
String shortest = words[0];
    String count = shortest;

    for (int i = 1; i < words.length ; i++) {
        if(shortest.length() == words[i].length()){//add word to shortest list
            shortest = words[i];
            count += ", " +shortest;
        }
        else if (words[i].length() < shortest.length())//found a shorter word
        {
            shortest = words[i];
            count = shortest;

        }
        //else word is longer, do nothing
    }
```

It is easier to track and trace if you handle the cases of shorter and equal separately. Also it feels like if you already looked at the zeroth word, you should not need to look at it again.